# Print selected messages in Gmail conversation

Tags: gmail, printing

I think that Gmail's Print all feature is very useful. However, can I use a similar function which allows me to print only selected messages within the conversation, probably using the Star?

Answer (score 1):

With the [Dynamite](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/djoedchmhkmbnkggjnbachnpikkabfhk) Chrome extension or the [Nuke Anything](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nuke-anything-enhanced/) add-on for Firefox you can remove the emails you don't want to print from Gmail's "print preview" page, then print the page.